# Pyglet flickers, alternates between two frames

Tags: python, opengl, framebuffer, pyglet, flicker

I am trying to subclass `pyglet.window.Window` to visualize an increasing number of randomly placed crosses. Unfortunately, Pyglet seems to store those crosses, not in one, but in two different, *alternating* frames. See the following GIF after about 50 iterations.

[image: switching between two frames]

Below is the code I used.

```py
import random
import pyglet


class Canvas(pyglet.window.Window):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.x = 0.
    self.y = 0.

    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .5)

  def update(self, dt: float) -> None:
    if self.has_exit:
      pyglet.app.exit()
    
    self.x = random.random() * self.width
    self.y = random.random() * self.height

  def on_draw(self) -> None:
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2f', (self.x - 10, self.y + 10., self.x + 10., self.y - 10.)))
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2f', (self.x - 10, self.y - 10., self.x + 10., self.y + 10.)))


def main() -> None:
  canvas = Canvas(width=1024, height=768)
  pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Could someone explain to me what's going on and maybe even provide a solution?

**Edit: I don't want to clear the screen between frames. I want to draw on top of the last frame to increase the number of crosses with every call of `self.update`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your edit: To draw on the previous frame, disable the double buffer: config = pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer=False) and pass that into the Window initialization.

---

You need to clear the screen before you draw, otherwise the previous frames will stay on the screen.

```py
  def on_draw(self) -> None:
    self.clear()
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2f', (self.x - 10, self.y + 10., self.x + 10., self.y - 10.)))
    pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2f', (self.x - 10, self.y - 10., self.x + 10., self.y + 10.)))
```

EDIT: If you want to increase the amount of rendered crosses, you will need to increase the amount of things rendered. Here is an example:

```py
import random
import pyglet

class Cross:
    def __init__(self, x, y, batch, size=10):
        self.size = size
        self._position = (x, y)
        self.verts = []
        self.create_vertices(x, y, batch)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self._position
        
    @position.setter
    def position(self, value):
        x, y = value
        self.verts[0].vertices[:] = (x - self.size, y + self.size, x + self.size, y - self.size)
        self.verts[1].vertices[:] = (x - self.size, y - self.size, x + self.size, y + self.size)
        self._position = value
        
    def create_vertices(self, x, y, batch):
        diag1 = batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None,
                      ('v2f', (x - self.size, y + self.size, x + self.size, y - self.size)))
                      
        diag2 = batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None,
                          ('v2f', (x - self.size, y - self.size, x + self.size, y + self.size)))
                          
        self.verts.append(diag1)
        self.verts.append(diag2)
    
    def delete(self):
        for vert in self.verts:
            vert.delete()
            
        self.verts.clear()


class Canvas(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.crosses = []

        self.cross_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, .5)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.create_cross, 1)

    def update(self, dt: float) -> None:
        if self.has_exit:
            pyglet.app.exit()
        
        # If you want the stars to move constantly, then uncomment this.
        #for cross in self.crosses:
        #    cross.position = (random.random() * self.width, random.random() * self.height)

    def create_cross(self, dt):
        cross = Cross(random.random() * self.width, random.random() * self.height, self.cross_batch, random.randint(3,10))
        self.crosses.append(cross)

    def on_draw(self) -> None:
        self.clear()
        self.cross_batch.draw()
        
    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.SPACE:
            for cross in self.crosses:
                cross.delete()
                
            self.crosses.clear()


def main() -> None:
  canvas = Canvas(width=1024, height=768)
  pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! i missed to mention that i want to avoid clearing the window and draw on top of the last frame instead. i updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Got it, in that case you want to disable the double buffer: `config = pyglet.gl.Config(double_buffer=False)` and pass that into the Window. This will allow you to draw on top of the previous buffer without the flickering between both.